# Android beginner need help on MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am new to Android Dev but I am trying to get a video to run when the app first starts.  I have the .mp4 file in a 'raw' folder under 'res' directory.  I have this so far...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer videotime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videotime = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lessonslearned);
    videotime.start();

}


protected void onResume() {
    Log.e("Pickle", "onResume");
    videotime = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lessonslearned);
    videotime.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. The video should start when the app starts, play all the way through, then stop.

Thanks!

EDIT: I get MEDIAPLAYER error (1, -2147483648)
basically the video does not play and the audio is not in the background.

Comment: You didnt even say what is going wrong, or post error

Comment: He's trying to start a MediaPlayer twice, that much is obvious

Comment: Just posted it sorry about that!

Comment: I originally did not have videotime start in the onCreate method but that didn't work either

Comment: to play a Video in a MediaPlayer a SurfaceView is required. Use a VideoView, read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `videotime.start()` in `onCreate`.  That will start the `MediaPlayer` before the activity is in the forefront.  You're calling `videotime.start()` twice.  Only call it in the `onResume()` method.

You also need to call `prepare` on the `MediaPlayer` before starting it.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for an example of how to properly start a `MediaPlayer`:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

This should work the same for video, but with different options.

Comment: One more quick question, what is the Uri myUri = .... supposed to be? Sorry I have literally been doing Android for 2 days thus far haha

Comment: I have used this for .mp3 but really works for video?

Comment: You can replace that with your resource instantiation on the MediaPlayer constructor instead.

Comment: `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` I thought OP trying to play video...

Comment: @meda that's just the developer.android.com example.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a better approach would be to use a [**VideoView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). I´m not completely sure but if you want to play a video with a `MediaPlayer` you need a `SurfaceView` to see the video, I have used Phoenixblade9 solution but only with .mp3 files.

You can use a `VideoView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video));
v.start();

}
```

just add the `VideoView` into your layout.

```
 <VideoView 
         android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         />
```

**Update**: to play a Video  in a `MediaPlayer` a `SurfaceView` is required.